# Crystal report does not render in browser

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using VS 2012 . Crystal report does not render/display in web browser.
I am using the following code.

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" Height="1202px" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="1104px" />
 <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
      <Report FileName="Test.rpt">
      </Report>
 </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

***Code Behind in Page Load event***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
        rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~/Test.rpt"));
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;

    }
```

When i run it in browser, only blank page shows. I did't find any solution on internet, help is required in such regards....

Comment: did you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753853/crystal-report-doesnt-display-in-asp-net-webpage-which-is-build-by-using-vs-2013

Comment: I have followed the instructions given in above link, then i got the following error, **HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**