# Crystal Reports do not show up in VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I am taking over a rather old .NET application and am attempting to upgrade it to the latest version.  I was able to upgrade it to .Net 4.0 and get it working with VS 2010, however, when I upgrade to VS 2013 none of the Crystal Reports actually show up when running from Studio's internal web server (haven't really tried in IIS but I would hope that would work).  I've tried doing some research on this and some folks get an error similar to mine about the crdb_adoplus not being able to find or load the pdb files and have stated that adding the following to the web.config helps:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

but I'm not concerned about debugging adoplus and this still does nothing for me.  To be specific the page loads but where the report should be there's just empty space and no other real errors in my log about it.  Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: What version of CR are you using?

Comment: @abramlimpin I grabbed the latest which I believe is 13 with update 13.  Again this is Crystal Reports for Visual Studio

Comment: Start with adding a new report with no data, just a text label to see if you can get something at all. And welcome to Crysthell reports.

Comment: This post helped me to solve this proble:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753853/crystal-report-doesnt-display-in-asp-net-webpage-which-is-build-by-using-vs-2013

Answer (score 2):

which version of chrystal reports do you have ?

Only chrystal reports with servcice pack 8 can be used with vs2013.

as stated

Service Pack 7 for “SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio” does not support Visual Studio 2013. Service Pack 8, ETA first quarter 2014, is planned to support VS 2013 as well as WIN 8.1.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  I originally was using service pack 8 and then tried 13.  Neither works.  Though both work fine for VS 2010

Comment: you have to try to rebuild  all the crystal reports jim sosa

Comment: I did.  Still nothing shows up.  I will say the project originally was built in an earlier version of Crystal reports and studio, but I've gone through and updated all the references in the web.config.