# To view Crystal Report in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I've Crystal reports store on my file-share, Now i want to read that file using  Asp.net(C#) webpage.
I want to create an exe file so that when user clicks on crystal report stored on file-share, it should get open in browser using my Asp.net(C#) webpage.

So I tried creating simple Asp.net(C#) app to open report from my local machine, I wrote below mentioned code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using CrystalDecisions.Enterprise;
using CrystalDecisions;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
namespace ReadCrystalReport
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ReportDocument r = new ReportDocument();
            r.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReportViewer1.rpt"));

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = r;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run it , I get blank page in browser no error nothing is shown, Could you please help me.
I'm using Visual studio 2013
Crystal report runtime V12...(as my reports are created in same version)

Thanks,
Ajit Mishra.

Comment: You should never `catch (Exception ex){  throw ex; }`. If you're going to do some error handling, then rethrow, just do `throw;`, don't do `throw ex;`. But if you're not going to do error handling, then don't bother catching it.

Comment: try the solution given in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709438/how-to-stop-crystal-report-viewer-from-asking-login-credentials-when-opening-sub

Comment: Hi Mason, I used Try catch just to see error details, but as suggested i removed it and checked the link you provided but its didn't resolved my issue,I'm still getting blank page when instead of crystal report(no error though)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be your issue: 
[[Crystal Report doesnt display in ASP.net webpage which is build by using VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753853/crystal-report-doesnt-display-in-asp-net-webpage-which-is-build-by-using-vs-2013/26770429#26770429)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753853/crystal-report-doesnt-display-in-asp-net-webpage-which-is-build-by-using-vs-2013/26770429#26770429)